# Javascript: Iterate Loop through object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Given the following json object structure, I need to fetch the id and value for each of the goals object as well as planet, people, and theme's object value also.

```
var data = {
  "goals": [{
      "id": "goal-09",
      "colour": "#FD6925",
      "priority": "People",
      "theme": "Sustainable Infrastructure",
      "title": "Industry, Innovation & Infrastructure",
      "value": 4
    },
    {
      "id": "goal-12",
      "colour": "#BF8B2E",
      "priority": "Planet",
      "theme": "Responsible Consumption",
      "title": "Responsible Consumption & Production",
      "value": 3
    },
    {
      "id": "goal-13",
      "colour": "#3F7E44",
      "priority": "Planet",
      "theme": "Environment",
      "title": "Climate Action",
      "value": 1
    }
  ],
  "planet": 50,
  "people": 50,
  "themes": {
    "Sustainable Infrastructure": 4,
    "Responsible Consumption": 3,
    "Environment": 1
  }
}
```

I have tried a couple of loops but this is a bit difficult, also you can have up to 17 goals and up to 5 different themes.

```
Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
  alert(key+" "+data[key]); // logs keys in myObject
});
```

This is where I am testing https://jsfiddle.net/dhzpqo4n/ and I will be fetching the json string from sessionStorage.

[image: sessionStorage]

the end goal is to construct a sql update statement to store these in a table with the following structure

[image]

**update**
I've come up with the following script which is a step in the right direction to construct my sql update statement with the values if each of the goals.

```
let i = 0
while (data.goals[i].id) {
  document.write(data.goals[i].id + "=" + data.goals[i].value + " ");
  i++
}
```

Which gives `goal-09=4 goal-12=3 goal-13=1`
https://jsfiddle.net/3r49zqsu/4/

Comment: You could use `for..in` loop. BTW what do you want?

Comment: Familiarize yourself with [how to access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON](/q/11922383/4642212) and how to [create objects](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) and use the available [`Object`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Static_methods) and [`Array`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Static_methods) methods (both static and on prototype).

Comment: `data.goals.forEach(...)`

Comment: @Barmar— "*…as well as planet, people, and theme's object value also*".

Comment: You should show the data structure you're trying to create, as "*…fetch the id and value…*" could mean just copying the object and leaving out the unwanted properties, or it might mean gathering the wanted properties and organising them differently.

Comment: @RobG those aren't arrays, there's nothing to iterate

Comment: Guys, thank you for your answers, what I am looking to get is a string such as the following `goal-09=4 goal-12=3 goal-13=1 planet=50 people=50 people=50 Sustainable Infrastructure=4 Responsible Consumption=3 Environment=1` so that I can construct an update syntax for my code @decpk @robg @barmar

Comment: `let i = 0
while (data.goals[i].id) {
  document.write(data.goals[i].id + "=" + data.goals[i].value + " ");
  i++
}` gives me goal-09=4 goal-12=3 goal-13=1 which is a step in the right direction

Comment: @DavidGarcia Answered please check is this what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array and push the result as follows:

**1)** if `val` is an array then loop through it to get the object's `id` and `value`. Then push it into `result` array.

**2)** If it is an object then first convert it into `key=value` form and then push it into result array.

**3)** else push the result as default `key=value` form

then finally join the array with `space`. That's it.

```js
var data = {
  goals: [
    {
      id: "goal-09",
      colour: "#FD6925",
      priority: "People",
      theme: "Sustainable Infrastructure",
      title: "Industry, Innovation & Infrastructure",
      value: 4,
    },
    {
      id: "goal-12",
      colour: "#BF8B2E",
      priority: "Planet",
      theme: "Responsible Consumption",
      title: "Responsible Consumption & Production",
      value: 3,
    },
    {
      id: "goal-13",
      colour: "#3F7E44",
      priority: "Planet",
      theme: "Environment",
      title: "Climate Action",
      value: 1,
    },
  ],
  planet: 50,
  people: 50,
  themes: {
    "Sustainable Infrastructure": 4,
    "Responsible Consumption": 3,
    Environment: 1,
  },
};

let result = [];
for (let key in data) {
  const val = data[key];
  if (Array.isArray(val)) {
    const temp = val.map(({ id, value }) => `${id}=${value}`);
    result = result.concat(temp);
  } else if (typeof val === "object") {
    const temp = Object.entries(val).map(([k, v]) => `${k}=${v}`);
    result = result.concat(temp);
  } else {
    result.push(`${key}=${val}`);
  }
}

console.log(result.join(" "));
```

You can simplify a bit

```js
var data = {
  goals: [
    {
      id: "goal-09",
      colour: "#FD6925",
      priority: "People",
      theme: "Sustainable Infrastructure",
      title: "Industry, Innovation & Infrastructure",
      value: 4,
    },
    {
      id: "goal-12",
      colour: "#BF8B2E",
      priority: "Planet",
      theme: "Responsible Consumption",
      title: "Responsible Consumption & Production",
      value: 3,
    },
    {
      id: "goal-13",
      colour: "#3F7E44",
      priority: "Planet",
      theme: "Environment",
      title: "Climate Action",
      value: 1,
    },
  ],
  planet: 50,
  people: 50,
  themes: {
    "Sustainable Infrastructure": 4,
    "Responsible Consumption": 3,
    Environment: 1,
  },
};

let result = [];
function pushInFinalResult(arr) {
  result = [...result, ...arr];
}

for (let key in data) {
  const val = data[key];
  if (Array.isArray(val)) {
    pushInFinalResult(val.map(({ id, value }) => `${id}=${value}`));
  } else if (typeof val === "object") {
    pushInFinalResult(Object.entries(val).map(([k, v]) => `${k}=${v}`));
  } else {
    pushInFinalResult([`${key}=${val}`]);
  }
}

console.log(result.join(" "));
```

**Removing spaces and `-`**

```js
var data = {
  goals: [
    {
      id: "goal-09",
      colour: "#FD6925",
      priority: "People",
      theme: "Sustainable Infrastructure",
      title: "Industry, Innovation & Infrastructure",
      value: 4,
    },
    {
      id: "goal-12",
      colour: "#BF8B2E",
      priority: "Planet",
      theme: "Responsible Consumption",
      title: "Responsible Consumption & Production",
      value: 3,
    },
    {
      id: "goal-13",
      colour: "#3F7E44",
      priority: "Planet",
      theme: "Environment",
      title: "Climate Action",
      value: 1,
    },
  ],
  planet: 50,
  people: 50,
  themes: {
    "Sustainable Infrastructure": 4,
    "Responsible Consumption": 3,
    Environment: 1,
  },
};

let result = [];
function pushInFinalResult(arr) {
  result = [...result, ...arr];
}

for (let key in data) {
  const val = data[key];
  if (Array.isArray(val)) {
    pushInFinalResult(
      val.map(({ id, value }) => `${id.replace("-", "")}=${value}`) // change
    );
  } else if (typeof val === "object") {
    pushInFinalResult(
      Object.entries(val).map(([k, v]) => `${k.replace(" ", "")}=${v}`) // change
    );
  } else {
    pushInFinalResult([`${key}=${val}`]);
  }
}

console.log(result.join(" "));
```

Comment: This is really good, does what I need, thank you for saving me countless hours of research, i have one last big ask, how hard is it to replace the dash in the goal-01 to goal01 and to remove spaces in the theme names, Sustainable Infrastructure to SustainableInfrastructure

Comment: You just have to make 2 changes and you are done

Comment: @DavidGarcia code edited and see Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
{goals: data.goals.map(k=>{return {id:k.id,value:k.value}}),planet:data.planet,people:data.people,themes:data.themes}
```

What happens here is it loops through all the goals and returns an object of only the id and the value.

Comment: Hey Proximity, what I am looking to get is to generate a string such as this `goal-09=4 goal-12=3 goal-13=1 planet=50 people=50 people=50 Sustainable Infrastructure=4 Responsible Consumption=3 Environment=1` to be used in a sql update statement